# How feathersjs rollback in hook?

Tags: mongoose, feathersjs

could someone please, provide an example of a rollback operation with feathersjs and mongoose. from a hook?
thank you

```
//hook befor 
hook.app.service('service1').update(data).then(data1Save =>
{
hook.app.service('service2').update(data2).catch(err=>{
// TODO rollback service1
});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no rollback in feathersjs, that construct is dependent of the data provider, and would need to be integrated manually most likely.

What I generally do is perform my updates on the edge components, then I update the dependent components after the edge items exist.

If you keep a list of the edge items within the dependent Item it will allow you to perform cleanup afterwards to ensure the updates went in.

// Example

```
app.service('transaction').create({...transactionInfo}).then(createdTransaction => {
  app.service('account').update(accountId,
    {
      $addToSet:{
        transactions:[createdTransaction._id] // add id to the parent
      },
      $set:{
        // nonTransactionsListdata
      }
    }
  ).then(updatedAccount => {
    // All updates should be successful
    // you can check to see if they took effect and resolve accordingly
  }).catch( err => {
    //Something happened, and may require a retry.
    // check validity of createdTransaction to ensure its being used correctly
  });
}).catch(err => {
  // Issue creating the transaction in the first place
});
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the example:

my rollaback solution (flag in hook):

```
  after: {
    all: []
    create: [myCreateHook({
      // create transaction
    service:'transaction',
    data:transactionInfo,
      // update transaction
    }),myAddArrayHook({
    path:'transactions.createdTransaction',
    service:'account',
   error:hook.isTransactionCatched})],   
  }
```

I was hoping to find a feathersJs system :( .

thanks again.